# How to use wildcards with aptitude?

Tags: command-line, aptitude

Is there a way to use wildcards with `aptitude` such as in the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove openoffice*.*
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=228309 indicates that it's possible via constructs such as `~n<package name>` and this is confirmed by the user manual http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s02.html.

`~n` in `~n<package name>` is a search pattern for matching package names. It's also possible to match other fields than packages' names, see http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html#tableSearchTermQuickGuide.

Here's an example. Say that you want `aptitude` to show every package with "redshift" in its name, then you issue

```
aptitude show ~nredshift
```

It should be combinable with other aptitude options, such as install and remove, too, e.g. to remove all installed packages with openoffice in their name you issue

```
sudo aptitude -P remove ~nopenoffice
```

Make sure to use the `-P` option when using search patterns to force aptitude to display a prompt before downloading, installing or removing          packages (the search pattern might have *many* matches and you'll want to be prompted before carrying out an action).

One thing that I haven't worked out is how to get the exact functionality of wildcards, e.g. that `openoffice*` matches every string *starting with* "openoffice" (`~nopenoffice` matches any string *containing* "openoffice"). Maybe a workaround is possible, e.g. to search for installed packages with a certain string in their names and then feed aptitude with their names.

Comment: -P is meant for never following symbolic links, not prompt

Comment: Also using  ~nredshift will not search for redshift, but ~nredshift. Also ~n is not any argument by default

Comment: Answer given by NorticUs is paartly correct. The correct syntax here would be ~n^redshift

Answer (score 7):

You just put it in quotes:

```
sudo apt-get remove "openoffice*"
```

Otherwise the shell would try to match this to the files of your current working directory.

Comment: The question is about `aptitude` and not `apt-get`. This solution does not work with aptitude.

Comment: @MichałŠrajer: no pathname expansion occur in quotes, both single and double

Comment: @enzotib: My mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. Removed comment.

Comment: ok, I don't get ... so can be done with aptitude or work in that way... sudo aptitude remove "openoffice*"

Comment: @raulricardo21 A similar thing can be done with aptitude, see [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62595/how-to-use-wildcards-with-aptitude/62676#62676).

Comment: @raulricardo21 This is the only correct answer. Please consider accepting this as the answer

Answer (score 5):

To match strings starting with a package name, prepend a `^` in front of it.
e.g: `aptitude search ~n^openoffice`

Comment: I does just the search portion, you should also mention how to get the search result